# Jquery find checked input element inside a container not working in ie9

Tags: jquery

I have created a custom checkbox of sorts . 
It basically is a set of 2 checkboxes.When the dom is ready both the checkboxes are checked . The user is allowed to uncheck only one.

---

This is how i went about implementing it.

I have a container like so

```
<div class="container">
     <input name="my_checkbox_1" type="checkbox" checked="checked">
     <label for="my_checkbox_1" class="on">Hello</label>
     <input name="my_checkbox_2" type="checkbox" checked="checked">
     <label for="my_checkbox_2" class="on">World</label>
</div>
```

now when a user clicks on label , i find the closest container

```
parent = $(this).closest(".container");
```

once i have the parent i find the number of checkboxes which are checked like so

```
len = $(parent).find("input:checkbox:checked").length;
```

if the len is 0 i try to alert the user with an appropriate error . This works in every other browser works but ie  (Am i allowed to say no surprise there ? ). but what am i doing wrong here ?

Please do keep in mind , i have a number of such containers with checkboxes having unique names.

I have created a fiddle with the code at 
http://jsfiddle.net/kiranruth/UeEyB/1/

Comment: try using `input[type=checkbox]` instead of `:checkbox`

Comment: @wirey tried that, din work .

Comment: try putting `var` in front of of your variables - that fixed it for me in IE8

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to declare parent as a local variable or rename it since you are overwriting [window's parent property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.parent)

I would just add var in front of your variables

```
var parent = $(this).closest(".container");
var len = $(parent).find("input:checkbox:checked").length;
```